# Pourquoi place-t-on une espace avant les ponctuations fortes ? — Why is there a space before certain punctuation marks?

Tags: histoire, typographie, ponctuation

Par exemple, le point d'exclamation `!`, le point d'interrogation `?` et le point-virgule `;` sont précédés d'une espace, contrairement à l'usage anglais. Historiquement, y a-t-il eu une raison ou un contexte propice à l'apparition de cette règle ?

On aurait pu penser que cette règle allait disparaitre pour des raisons d'économie de caractères, et de temps. Ce phénomène s'est produit en anglais lors de la disparition des doubles espaces entre les phrases. Y a-t-il des exemples de ce genre de simplifications dans l'usage français actuel ?

---

For example, the exclamation `!`, the question mark `?` and the semi-colon `;` all have a space before them in French (compared to English).  Is there a historical or some other contextual reason as to why or how this came to be?

One would think that this usage would have deteriorated over time to conserve space (on paper) and time (to type that extra space).  An example of this happening in English would be the reduction of double spacing between sentences down to single spacing.  Or are there examples of this already happening commonly in French now?

Comment: Related question in [meta](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/non-breaking-spaces-and-punctuation-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: This is occasionally seen in English too, perhaps only English of a certain vintage and style and from a certain country. I'll try to keep an eye open for examples.

Comment: *espace* n'est féminin que lorsque tu parles du caractère (utilisé en imprimerie). Bien qu'à prioris ta question ne porte pas sur ceci, on pourrait l'interpréter dans les 2 sens. L'edit n'est pas indispensable mais reste souhaitable.

Comment: Aussi sur [_ELU_](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4645), [_Linguistics_](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12642).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47633/discussion-on-question-by-bryan-denny-pourquoi-place-t-on-une-espace-avant-les-p).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

#### Explication

D'après *Orthotypographie*, de Jean-Pierre Lacroux, à [*Ponctuation*](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/point_cardinal-proverbe.html#Ponctuation) :

> […] cette convention est motivée, utile, efficace, salement subtile. Comme vous le savez — et comme le pressentaient les typographes d’antan —, le lecteur ne lit pas lettre à lettre. Les mots ont une « silhouette » ; or, quand elles ne sont pas isolées par une espace, les ponctuations dites « hautes » (`;` `:` `!` `?`) modifient cette « forme globale » et par conséquent gênent la perception du lecteur. Parfois fort peu, voire pas du tout, parfois considérablement. […] Ce parasitage n’est bien entendu pas à craindre avec les ponctuations basses (`.` `,` `…`).

#### La règle, et sa cause :

> […] les ponctuations hautes comme le point-virgule, les points d’exclamation et d’interrogation appartiennent davantage à la phrase ou au membre de phrase qui les précède qu’à la phrase ou au membre qui les suit… Dans la typographie soignée, l’espace de gauche est donc très inférieure à celle de droite.

Soit, pour du texte numérique, *une espace fine* — évidemment *insécable*, pour ne pas isoler une marque de ponctuation en début de ligne — *avant la ponctuation haute* (`?` `!` `;` `:`). Avec une éventuelle exception :

> Seul le deux-points, qui établit une sorte d’égalité, est isolé par deux espaces égales. Toutefois, certains typographes préconisent de diminuer un peu l’espace de gauche (à mon sens, ils n’ont pas tort…).

Le deux-points peut se passer de la finesse de son espace à gauche, qui n'en demeure pas moins insécable.

---

#### Motivation

*Orthotypographie*, by Jean-Pierre Lacroux, provides us a good reason to do so, see [Punctuation](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/point_cardinal-proverbe.html#Ponctuation).

> […] this convention is motivated, useful, efficient, badly subtle. As you may know – and as anticipated by typographers from the old ages –, readers do not read letter by letter. Words have ‘outlines’. When so-called ‘high’ punctuation marks (`;` `:` `!` `?`) are placed right next to a word, they affect its shape, thereby hampering the reader's perception, be it by a minor or an important factor. This phenomenon is not to be feared with lower punctuation marks (`.` `,` `…`).

#### The rule and its explanation :

> […] high punctuations like the semi-colon and the exclamation and question marks pertain more to what precedes than to what follows them. In fine typography, the space preceding them is therefore much narrower than the one following them.

Which means, on digital supports, that *a narrow space* – obviously an *unbreakable* one, to prevent a punctuation mark from undesirably opening the next line – should precede ‘high’ punctuation marks (`;` `:` `!` `?`). With one possible exception :

> Only the colon, which establishes some kind of balance, is surrounded by identically-sized spaces. However, some typographers recommend to lessen the amount of space on the left (which makes sense, in my opinion).

Now, narrowness being optional before colons, those spaces must nevertheless remain unbreakable.

Comment: La première réponse qui semble donner une explication intéressante. Merci beaucoup ! :)

Comment: I find the argument about readability to be faulty. Why do English writers not put a blank before 'high' punctuation signs? Why do people from Québec follow English usage. What do Germans do? If readability is a criterion, why do we right-justify our te ts?

Comment: @B.Scholl: Quoting my favorite part : *this convention is motivated, useful, efficient, badly subtle*. It's merely a *useful and efficient convention*, not a universal rule. English writers don't follow it because they didn't see the *motivation* why (*badly subtle*). Quebecers don't simply follow English usage : they'd follow the convention BUT when lacking thin spaces, they'd rather have none than a full one AND their generalized lack of *finesse* is the standard. [Official source](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2039). Right-justification also helps readability, afaik.

Comment: Beaucoup intéressante, mais je me demande si on a fait des recherches scientifiques sur cette question!

Comment: To add to @Nikana Reklawyks' comment, Québec graphic designers are taught to follow the various thin spaces.

Answer (score 19):

I think the main criterion is readability. Old typeset texts were not very strict with spaces. In the 16th century for example, you could find typeset texts that had spaces removed after comas to make a text fit on a line. It was also common to have apostrophes without a space of their own, so the apostrophe ended up on top of the letter following it.

While these practices of using non-breaking and thin non-breaking spaces have made their way to become rules in French typography, it is interesting to note that many Belgians do not add thin non-breaking spaces before `?` and `!`.

Comment: That was the idea with [my answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46/is-there-an-explanation-for-why-there-is-a-space-before-certain-punctuation-marks/48#48) too. :)

Comment: We do not use a non-breaking space before those signs in Quebec French either.

Answer (score 14):

The rule is:

- No space before simple punctuation marks (`, . …` etc)
- one space before double punctuation marks (`? ; : !` etc)

I don't see any explanation to justify this use over the English rules. But this surely have to do with the manual printing of documents, when we used lead blocks to ink the paper.

Comment: You do not answer the question: why? Why would English and French have different rules (the history of printing techniques is parallel in England and France after all)?

Comment: Note that, strictly speaking, the space before "double" punctuation marks is different from the one *after* simple punctuation marks: it is a *thin space* ('espace fine'), which is often replace by a *non-breaking space* ('espace insécable'), although I believe typography specialists would argue the two are different...

Comment: I don't quite agree with your spacing rules. While `:` is preceded by a non-breaking space, `;`, `?` and `!` must be preceded by a non-breaking thin space. Entire spaces before them look quite ugly.

Comment: @Raphink: oui ça me perturbe aussi les espaces complets. Ce serait bien si M'vy en parlait dans sa réponse, ça me parait même incontournable dans le cadre de cette question.

Answer (score 13):

Au Canada, il n'est pas d'usage de mettre une espace insécable devant le `?`, le `!` et le `;`. (Voir [Guide du rédacteur](http://www.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect6&info0=6.13#zz6)). Lorsque nous révisons des textes à mon travail, nous considérons ces espaces comme étant erronées.

J'ai appris dans un des mes cours à l'université, qu'anciennement cette espace était d'usage pour des raisons de lisibilité lorsqu'on tapait à la dactylo. Son usage aurait disparu dans certaine parties de la Francophonie après l'avènement de l'ordinateur.

Malheureusement, je ne trouve aucune référence à ce sujet en ligne sauf [ceci](http://j.poitou.free.fr/pro/html/typ/ponctuation.html).

Comment: La question reste essentiellement "**pourquoi** les règles sont-elles différentes partout ?"

Comment: Qc. [_BDL_](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2039) : « Si l’on dispose de l'espace fine, il est conseillé de l'utiliser devant le point-virgule, le point d'exclamation et le point d'interrogation. Dans le cas contraire, l’espace fine est supprimée et équivaut à une absence d’espacement. Toute autre espace est rendue par un espacement, ou blanc. »

Comment: lorsqu'on tapait à la dactylo??? On vous a enseigne à lui donné des coups? Plutôt lorsqu'on ***dactylographiait*** ou lorsqu'on taper à la machine....

Answer (score 12):

There should be a **non-breaking** space before punctuation marks composed of at least two elements.

I believe this is for readability. It could be lost if people forget more and more about the existence of a *non-breaking* space, yet still want to avoid line breaks between the punctuation mark and the word before.

Comment: That's the convention, but the question was is there a reason for it?

Comment: Actually, it's even finer than that: there is a non-breaking space before a period for example, but it's a non-breaking **thin space** before a semi-colon, an exclamation mark or a question mark...

Comment: You do not answer the question: why? Why would English and French have different rules (the history of printing techniques is parallel in England and France after all)?

Comment: As for the why, I wanted to convey the same reason as [this answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46/is-there-an-explanation-for-why-there-is-a-space-before-certain-punctuation-marks/108#108) indeed. :)

Comment: [The accepted answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/4401/12979) suggests that the rule is based rather on the height (“strength”) of the punctuation mark than on the number of components it has, though it seems to me that it comes to the same thing in practice.

Answer (score 7):

Just a random idea out of my hat, pure speculation, no references:

The intonation given to interrogative and exclamation sentences is quite particular, so you are better off if you know the sentence ending punctuation in advance. So, maybe the extra space makes the symbol a bit **more visible** from far before, allowing the reader to give the sentence the appropriate intonation?

That does not explain the semicolon though.

Comment: Maybe.  But you then think French would have inherited Spanish's ¿ and ¡ (which are at the beginning of their sentences to do exactly what you're describing).

Comment: @Bryan: Great remark! Maybe both are two different solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

- If you look at older books, more spacing was used than nowadays.  For instance, it was customary to put a 1pt space after commas. Likewise, parentheses were more spaced around what they contain than they are now.  See for instance in the [Spécimen des nouveaux caractères de la fonderie et de l'imprimerie de P. Didot l'ainé](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Kdmpyl_TXQMC&pg=PT12).  The current taste seems to be for fewer spaces than before.
- If you look at books on typography, some English and American authors want more space and even suggest modifying the font and increasing the left bearing of the front characters, whereas the French tradition calls only for a thin space.  Likewise, I remember that someone on a typography mailing list did a survey on fonts and found out that French font designers tended to have a smaller left bearing than English and American ones.  So the difference seems to be more in the means used to achieve the spacing than in the spacing itself.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that historically, in typography, its a narrow no-break space which must be inserted between the word and the exclamation mark, question mark, the semicolon or the colon.

This narrow no-break space being available only in specialized software, different trends have emerged:

- using a normal non-breaking space in Europe;
- in Quebec, not put anything at all.

More details here:

[For impeccable non-breaking spaces](http://translate.google.fr/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://www.druide.com/points_de_langue_13.html&act=url) (original: [Pour des espaces insécables impeccables](http://www.druide.com/points_de_langue_13.html))

These articles may also interest you:

[A (he) space or a (she) space?](http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://www.druide.com/points_de_langue_03.html) (original: [Un espace ou une espace?](http://www.druide.com/points_de_langue_03.html))
[Colon and quotation marks: the "Minutes"](http://translate.google.fr/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://www.lexpress.fr/culture/deux-points-et-guillemets-le-proces-verbal_779087.html&act=url) (original: [Deux-points et guillemets : le " procès-verbal "](http://www.lexpress.fr/culture/deux-points-et-guillemets-le-proces-verbal_779087.html))

---

La raison est qu'historiquement, en typographie, c'est une espace fine insécable qui doit être intercalé entre le mot et le point d'exclamation, d'interrogation le point virgule ou les deux points.

Cette espace fine n'étant disponible que dans les logiciels spécialisés, différentes tendances sont apparues :

- en Europe francophone, mettre une espace insécable habituelle ;
- au Québec, ne rien mettre du tout.

Plus de précisions ici :

[Pour des espaces insécables impeccables](http://www.druide.com/points_de_langue_13.html)

Ces articles peuvent aussi vous intéresser :

[Un espace ou une espace?](http://www.druide.com/points_de_langue_03.html)
[Deux-points et guillemets : le " procès-verbal "](http://www.lexpress.fr/culture/deux-points-et-guillemets-le-proces-verbal_779087.html)

Comment: Note: le texte du dernier lien a visiblement subi une transformation automatique des guillemets français en guillemets droits, mais en conservant les espaces, ce qui le rend assez pénible à lire.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez En effet

Comment: Les liens vers du google translate c'est une très mauvaise idée. Laisse le lecteur choisir d'y avoir recours seul s'il en a besoin.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Il y a les liens originaux dans la version française...

Comment: « Cette espace fine n'étant disponible que dans les logiciels spécialisés » espace fine insécable vue chez toutes les distributions de Linux et même chez Windows avec des pilotes de clavier alternatifs. Par exemple chez moi Alt Gr + Shift + Space pour les fines insécables.

Comment: Si un pilote de clavier alternatif n'est pas un logiciel spécialisé, je me demande ce que c'est ^^. Le grand public, le tout venant, c'est ce dont la majorité des gens dispose. Et puis, c'est quand même assez récent tout ça, j'avais une machine à écrire quand j'était petit, et il n'était pas question de pilotes alternatif.