# Which space should one use before punctuation ? Does it depend on the technology?

Tags: usage, orthographe, ponctuation, typographie

French puts extra spacing between words and certain punctuation marks including *?*.

But should it be a space, a half a space, or a non-breaking space (`&nbsp`) technically? Or does it vary between handwriting, old-fashioned typewriters, typesetting, ASCII <sup>(or ISO 8859-1)</sup>, Unicode, HTML, TeX / LaTeX?

I seem to recall of once reading of spaces of various fractional sizes besides half - can that be right?

Comment: Related question: [Is there an explanation for why there is a space before certain punctuation marks? / Espaces avant les ponctuations fortes](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46/is-there-an-explanation-for-why-there-is-a-space-before-certain-punctuation-marks)

Comment: I think this should be closed as a duplicate of the one you found yourself.

Comment: The referenced question asks for the origin of the difference (even if some answers contains information) while this one ask for the usage.

Comment: @Un francophone: That is precisely what I was going to say when I saw the question had been proposed as a dupe. And why I kept my question after I found the older one. There are some good answers here specific to usage too. I thought I included the usage tag but I will now add it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Si on regarde dans quelques livres (*Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale*, *Manuel de typographie française élémentaire* de Y. Perrousseaux, *Le Ramat européen de la typographie* de A. Ramat et R. Muller) proposant des marches typographiques, on remarque qu'il y a des variations légères dans leur proposition. La source des variations peut être un besoin de simplification pour les deux derniers (leur public n'est pas le même), le fait que l'auteur du troisième soit canadien (même si l'objectif de l'édition européenne est d'éliminer cette influence) et qu'il est plus descriptif de l'usage quand les deux premiers sont prescriptifs.  L'usage varie en effet et par exemple un journal, avec ses colonnes étroites, a de bonnes raisons d'utiliser une marche différente
qu'un livre.

Le *lexique* utilisent trois sortes d'espaces:

- espace-mot (de taille fixe, l'espace désiré entre les mots)
- espace justifiante (normalement l'espace-mot mais de taille variable pour permettre la justification)
- l'espace fine (de taille fixe, plus petite que l'espace-mot)

  ```
  .   rien             justifiante
  ,   rien             justifiante
  ;   fine insécable   justifiante
  !   fine insécable   justifiante
  ?   fine insécable   justifiante
  :   mot insécable    justifiante
  -   justifiante      justifiante
  «   justifiante      mot insécable
  »   mot insécable    justifiante
  (   justifiante      rien
  )   rien             justifiante
  [   justifiante      rien
  ]   rien             justifiante
  ```

mais si on regarde leur pratique, l'espace avant les `:` est en fait une espace justifiante insécable et leur espace-mot insécable après `«` et avant `»` est peut-être une espace fine dans les corps les plus petits (elle n'est en tout cas pas justifiante).

Y. Perrousseaux a la même table mais ne fait pas de différence entre espace-mot et espace justifiante.  Sa pratique est celle d'une espace justifiante. En note il suggère de remplacer l'espace fine par l'espace-mot quand on ne dispose pas d'espace fine.

A. Ramat fait de même mais le choix entre l'espace-mot et l'espace fine n'est pas conditionné à une contrainte d'indisponibilité.

La valeur des espaces varie au moins suivant les fontes.  L'espace mot fait normalement entre un quart et un tiers de quadratin. L'espace fine est d'un huitième de quadratin.  En pratique, je sais que les typographes soucieux des détails (et quel typographe ne l'est pas ?) ajustent ces suggestions suivant leur contexte.

En parlant d'ajustement, certains livres anglais (*The Elements of Typographic Style* de R. Bringhurst par exemple) suggèrent d'augmenter l'approche gauche des caractères `!` et `?` et on a remarqué sur les listes francophones consacrées à la typographie que les approches gauches et droites de ces caractères tendaient à varier suivant les traditions typographiques du pays du concepteur de la fonte et devaient donc parfois être adaptées pour respecter celle de l'utilisateur.

Les traditions changent avec le temps.  Par exemple, au moins en France, une espace d'un point était laissée avant les virgules, leur donnant un effet détaché étrange à mon œil.

Finalement, une note de terminologie.  « Espace » est féminin quand le mot désigne l'espace entre les mots et masculin quand il désigne un espace non imprimé (on utilise aussi « blanc » dans ce sens).

---

Looking at three different books (*Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale*, *Manuel de typographie française élémentaire* de Y. Perrousseaux, *Le Ramat européen de la typographie* de A. Ramat et R. Muller), there are slight variations between their recommendations, and some of the variations may be due to the need of simplification for the later two and a Canadian influence for the later one, and the fact that the first two propose a « marche typographique » (I don't know the English word) and thus are prescriptive while the later is more descriptive of the usages.

The *lexique* has three kinds of spaces:

- word space (fixed size, the desired space between word)
- justifying space (varying size, target is the word space)
- thin space (smaller than the word space)

  ```
  .   nothing     justifying
  ,   nothing     justifying
  ;   thin        justifying
  !   thin        justifying
  ?   thin        justifying
  :   word        justifying
  -   justifying  justifying
  «   justifying  word
  »   word        justifying
  (   justifying  nothing
  )   nothing     justifying
  [   justifying  nothing
  ]   nothing     justifying
  ```

but their practice in the book seem to be inconsistent with what they suggest.  The word space before a `:` is a justifying non breakable space, the word space after `«` and before `»` is for sure not justifying (it could even be a thin space).

Y. Perrousseaux has the same table but doesn't make a difference between word and justifying space (only write about word space).

A. Ramat does the same thing and allow a word space as an alternative for fine space.

The precise value of the different spaces vary.  Word space is about 1/4 to 1/3 of an em. Fine space is smaller but none of the book give a value.  I know that detail minded typographers (are there any other?) tend to adjust what the system give them.

An additional note about spacing before `!` and `?`.  Some English book on typography suggest modifying some fonts which have *insufficient left bearing* for those characters (*The Elements of Typographic Style* of R. Bringhurst for instance) while in discussion on french typography related lists have remarked that left and right bearings in fonts tend to depend on typographic tradition in the country of the font designer and thus require fine adjustment of the spacing so that the result is correct for the typographic tradition of the text.

A final remark, tradition change.  At least in France, n the nineteenth century, a 1pt space was put before the comma for instance giving them a strange detached aspect to modern eyes.

Comment: il faut se décider sur le genre de « espace » (qui est bien féminin en typographie) :-)

Comment: Si je ne me prompte pas, il y a une nuance entre espace féminin et espace masculin en typographie (« une espace fine permet de laisser un petit espace »).  Il faudrait que je vérifie d'abord et que je relise après pour corriger mes erreurs, mais je suis au boulot.

Comment: J'ai vérifié et, normalement, utilisé le genre correct.

Comment: Pas de problème, merci pour l'explication sur la nuance. C'est subtil :-)

Comment: @cadrian, note que j'ai fait aussi des corrections (mon commentaire précédant pouvait laisser penser qu'elles n'avaient pas été nécessaires).

Comment: Oui, j'ai remarqué. Merci pour le travail :-)

Comment: Ça fait plaisir de lire une réponse détaillée et correcte sur la typographie ! :-)

Answer (score 12):

Up to my knowledge, the correct space size, used in French typography, before question marks, semicolons, etc… is a little larger than half a space. As for the various ways to obtain it:

1. Handwriting: some spacing is often seen before those punctuation marks.
2. Old-fashioned typewriters: one full space was the only solution.
3. typesetting: I don't know, were they using proper short sorts ?
4. ASCII or ISO8859-1: one full space is the only solution.
5. Unicode: there is a “narrow no-break space” (`U+202F`) showing up as

   > “a ; b” instead of “a ; b”

   (first *a* is followed by the narrow no-break space).
6. HTML: one can use `&thinsp;` (most browsers support it nowadays), or `&nbsp;`, when direct unicode input is not supported.
7. LaTeX: use internationalization packages, everything is going to end up “perfect”.

Comment: For point 7: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#French - it does indeed include automatic spacing, among many other things.

Answer (score 6):

It should be noted that not all French-speaking regions put an extra space between words and certain punctuation marks. It is frequent in Canadian French, for example, to have no space before a question mark or other marks for which other regions would indeed add a space.

That being said, I believe half a space is what is  usually recommended, but seeing as most common programs do not support such spaces, a non-breaking space would be in order so that you do not end up with your punctuation mark all by itself at the beginning of a new line.