# Séparation entre le nombre et l’unité

Tags: nombres, typographie, espace-insécable, unités

Quelle séparation doit se trouver entre un nombre et une unité ? Non seulement pour les unités SI mais aussi pour les unités littérales comme « année ». Doit-on dire 1500 ans (espace insécable), 1500 ans (espace insécable fine) ou bien encore 1500ans (immédiatement accolé) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les règles typographiques demandent un espace insécable entre le nombre et l'unité de temps.

[Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heure#Typographie) donne une bonne référence sur ce sujet. De mémoire, il y avait un article là-dessus sur le site de l'observatoire de Meudon mais impossible de le retrouver.

Comment: Mais est-ce valable pour toutes les unités de temps (jour, semaine, moi année, siècle, et millénaire) ou seulement pour celles inférieures à la journée ?

Comment: C'est valable pour toutes les unités de temps.

Answer (score 4):

Il faut une espace insécable, sa valeur (fine, mot ou justifiante) me semble plutôt une question de marche typographique que d'usage général comme c'est le cas pour les espaces autour des [ponctuations](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/603/176). Ça ne m'étonnerait pas que certaines marches fassent une différence entre les unités abréviées (où j'aurais tendance à mettre une espace fine) et celles écrites en toutes lettres (où je mettrais une espace justifiante).