# Should I be strict about thin spaces before high punctuation marks? — Dois-je être strict concernant les espaces fines avant les ponctuations hautes ?

Tags: typographie, ponctuation, espace-insécable

I read [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46/pourquoi-place-t-on-une-espace-avant-les-ponctuations-fortes-why-is-there-a) about the spacing around some punctuation marks. Should I be strict about using a narrow space before a `?`, `!`, etc., or can I just use a normal, non-breaking space? The text is in a game.

---

Je lisais [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46/pourquoi-place-t-on-une-espace-avant-les-ponctuations-fortes-why-is-there-a), à propos des espaces autour des ponctuations. Dois-je être strict concernant les espaces **fines** avant `?`, `!`, etc., ou puis-je utiliser une espace insécable ? Le texte est celui d'un jeu.

Comment: Le mieux est d'utiliser des espaces fines, mais je pense que la plupart des gens ne connaît même pas l'existence de ce type d'espace.

Comment: Je ne sais même pas comment les taper sur mon clavier…

Comment: @Édouard, et c'est l'autre problème ! Dois-je copier et coller l'espace chaque fois ?

Comment: I suppose you are talking about a video game. Choose wisely your font. I think you don't have to worry about this, let be honest, nobody will never notice. Use regular spaces

Comment: @Édouard Avec LibreOffice ou OpenOffice, les ***; : ? !*** sont précédés d'espaces fines insécables (Options, ..Writer .. Aide au formatage)

Comment: J’utilise LaTeX en général pour mes documents papiers ou PDF, pas de problème de ce côté-là. Mais dans un email ? Où dans ce commentaire ? Je mets des espaces insécables, faute de mieux.

Comment: @Stéphane, thanks for the edits! Now I just need to remember how and when to use them!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spaces between a text and a punctuation mark such as ? ; : and ! in french are only here to make reading easier.

It is customary in french to use thin, non-breaking spaces but it is not required, it is only a typographic convention (as described in the 'Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale'). And even in those conventions, a certain leeway is allowed concerning the width of the space that should be used.

The only thing that should be respected is that those spaces be made non-breaking as it will avoid a punctuation mark to be separated from the last word of the sentence, making it much easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que le mieux est de faire simple, utilise un espace "classique". La différence est infime, et ne sera quasiment pas perçue.

---

Be simple, just use the "normal" space. There's not a big difference, and this difference will not be noticed.

Comment: This answer would be the better if the question wasn't explicitly mentioning the context being a fixed translation for a game. In casual text-based exchange like boards, mails and chats, noone will expect (nor even spot) thin-spaces, it would be useless. In a game, on the other hand, it could make sense.