# Puis-je répondre à cette question en cette manière ? "Tu as vu le dernier film de Chéreau ?"

Tags: grammaire, négation, registre-familier

Si quelqu'un me demande :

> Tu as vu le dernier film de Chéreau ?

Est-ce que la réponse suivante est valable ?

> Non, je ne l'ai pas vu. Il est bien ?

La source du problème : dans mon livre, ils écrivent

> ... à l'oral et dans un registre de langue familier, la particule négative "ne" disparait souvent ; par exemple :
>
> - Tu as vu le dernier film de Chéreau ?
> - Non, je l'ai pas vu. Il est bien ?

Et je me demandais où je dois placer le "ne" !

Comment: S'il y a des erreurs grammaticales dans ma question, corrigez-les s'il vous plait

Comment: Ton livre a raison, le **ne** disparaît à l'oral. S'il disparaît c'est qu'on ne le met pas donc pas besoin de le placer. Ton livre dit bien « à l'oral », déconseillé à l'écrit.

Comment: Corrections : 1) on dit *un problème*, ce qui donne *Source du problème* ; 2) en français, on met un espace avant et après la ponctuation formée de plusieurs caractères (**?**, **!**, **;**, etc.) ; 3) *quelqu'un* et non *quelqu'une* (ce dernier mot est extrêmement rare).

Comment: @SimonDechamps merci beaucoup. Est-ce que la règle dans votre remarque 2) est aussi applicable au guillemet (") ? (J'ai effacé mon dernier commentaire parce qu'elle contient beaucoup des erreurs)

Comment: @SimonDéchamps les espaces avant la ponctuation est un débat qu'on a déjà eu ici, et la conclusion est "ce n'est pas obligatoire" :)

Comment: @Quelqu'un Ce n'est pas applicable à ces guillemets **" "** mais ça l'est à ces guillemets **« »**. Néanmoins, comme Random évoque un débat sur le sujet qui semble conclure que cette règle n'est pas obligatoire, je vous conseille de vous renseigner sur ce sujet, très vaste.

Comment: @Random Par curiosité, à quelle discussion faites-vous allusion ? J'ai toujours lu qu'en français, on mettait une espace (insécable et si possible fine sauf pour les deux points) avant ?;:!. (cette convention est décrite dans [cette réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/4401/6774)) et que cette pratique était suffisamment répandue pour paraître obligatoire.

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues c'était un débat dans des commentaires, comme ici, et cela date de plusieurs mois, donc je serai incapable de donner un lien :S

Comment: Concernant les règles typographiques de la ponctuation, il me semble en effet qu'elles ne sont pas si souples que ça, sauf pour raisons techniques (certains types d'espaces par exemple sont bien plus compliqués à taper que d'autres). Etant en Belgique, et ces règles étant différentes en néerlandais, anglais et Français, je suis souvent confronté au problème et n'ai jamais entendu dire qu'on faisait comme on voulait... Pareil pour l'anglais en fait. Cela dit, ca reste du coupage de cheveux en 4 et n'a selon moi rien à voir avec la grammaire...

Comment: On rencontrera plus souvent à l'oral « T'as vu l'dernier film de Chéreau ? », voire « T'y as vu le dernier... » à Marseille.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La réponse :

> Non, je ne l'ai pas vu. Il est bien ?

Est correcte.

Par contre, à l'oral, on éludera très souvent le *ne*, ce qui donnera :

> Non, je l'ai pas vu. Il est bien ?

Mais je ne le ferais pas à l'écrit, sauf sur un tchat ou un forum.

D'ailleurs, note que *Tu as vu ?* et *Il est bien ?* sont également du registre oral, puisqu'on écrirait plutôt *Est-ce que tu as vu ?* et *Est-ce qu'il est bien ?* en langage courant, voire *As-tu vu ?* et *Est-il bien ?* en langage soutenu.

Comment: Ah, merci beaucoup!

Comment: A l'oral, j'irais même plus loin en disant « j'l'ai pas vu »