# Pourquoi écrit-on “déses-péré” avec un trait d’union dans Le Seigneur des Anneaux ?

Tags: typographie, trait-d-union

J’ai récemment acheté *Le Seigneur des Anneaux* dans l’édition “L’Intégrale”, Editions Pocket. Là j’ai vu qu’on écrit partout “**déses-péré**” aussi sur une seule ligne, par exemple sur la page 93:

> “*Mon vieux papa serait tellement déses-péré*”.

Y a-t-il une bonne raison pour ça, ou est-ce une faute ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas seulement à cette page mais tout le long du livre.
Par conséquent je ne pense pas que c'est une erreur d'impression ou de l'éditeur.
Moi aussi je me pose cette question et si quelqu'un sait répondre je lui en serait reconnaissant d'indiquer son hypothèse.
Merci d'avance.

Answer (score 7):

Aucune raison si c'est sur la même ligne, je pense que c'est une erreur à l'impression.

Comment: Indeed, or at the typesetting stage. One sometimes finds in less than ideally formatted documents that the line breaks shift, and depending on how hyphenation has been implemented, one may end up with literal hyphen characters rather than ones dynamically determined at display time! I've noticed that Word in particular is bad at this... copy and paste some text with line-end hyphens from Word into InDesign, and you'll find literal hyphens where the lines ended in Word now arbitrarily placed in ID. Not that publishers likely use that workflow, but for any typesetting user to be aware of. :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak: I’m used to this sort of thing in casually produced documents (though I had put it down to people not realising they needed an **optional** hyphen), but I had really not expected it in a professionally produced, presumably type-read book. Perhaps _Editions Pocket_ are unusually incompetent, but I also thought they might possibly be right as I also suspected the spaces before colons of being errors until I found [this explanation](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46/pourquoi-place-t-on-une-espace-avant-les-ponctuations-fortes-why-is-there-a?rq=1).

Comment: I think seeking an explanation is always the right place to start! (For example, if it had been between "dés" and "espéré", one might have wondered if there was some unexpected respect for etymology in play.) Sometimes you give up and remember that all publishers make mistakes. For example, [this NYT article](http://ow.ly/jowW309iUgD) from January includes the poorly punctuated line *"This book is wild." I said.* :p For *désespéré*, line ends can shift for many reasons and if the hyphens are literal characters in whatever layout workflow they use then not every stray one might get hunted down.

Comment: Apparemment cela ne se produit pas 1 seule fois, mais partout, ce qui devient plus étrange...